# Listview Search issue

Tags: android, listview, search

I have a listview that working perfet.Today I added a search function to the listview using this code

```
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
```

The problem: I have 114 items on my listview and the selected item depends on the position, when I do search and press on the item that I found it will return the position 1, I want to return the position of that item before the search.. not the new position, is there anyway to solve it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it will return the position of the item based on the current lenght of your list view/adapter.

Why would it matter?

If you want to start a different activity based on the item clicked, there are many ways to do it. Using the position in the list to choose the activity works **ONLY** when the positions are fixed, which is not your case, since the user can filter the items.

Instead, start the activity based on the content of the item clicked.

Say for instance, your listview is populated using the following items:

```
public static final String [] PLANETS = {
        "Mercury",
        "Venus",
        "Earth",
        "Mars",
        "Jupiter",
        "Saturn",
        "Uranus",
        "Neptune",
};
```

Using the following `ArrayAdapter`:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.text1, PLANETS);
```

Then you can edit your `OnItemClickListener` to start the activity based on the actual planet selected, not the position selected.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnPlanetOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int iistPosition, long l) {
        //Notice I don't get the value from the String array
        //Rather, I tell the adapter to give me the text from the selected item. 
        String planet = mAdapter.getItem(iistPosition);
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(Example.this, NextActivity.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("planet", planet);
    }
};
```

If you are using a custom adapter it's even easier.

**EDIT** It is unfortunate that because of the way your mp3 files are named you must depend on the list position to get appropiate file.

In that case you could try a few workarounds, for instance:

- If your list view is populated with a set `ArrayList` or just a `List`, you could first get the text of the item selected, and then get the actual array position based on the text of the item selected.

Like this:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnPlanetOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int iistPosition, long l) {
        //get the text of the current item
        String planet = mAdapter.getItem(iistPosition);
        //get the position of this planet in the original unfiltered array
        int actualListPosition = PLANETS_ARRAY.indexOf(planet);
        //handle the click based on the actualListPosition
    }
};
```

I hope that helps

Comment: because on my setOnItemClickListener i'm getting the position and go to another activity depends on the item that i selected!

Comment: if(position+1<10)
            {
             new Player()
                .execute("http://www.qurandownloads.com/Audio/Yahya_Hawa/mp3/"+ "00"+(position+1) +".mp3");
             
            }
            else if(position+1<100)
            {
             new Player()
                .execute("http://www.qurandownloads.com/Audio/Yahya_Hawa/mp3/"+ "0"+(position+1) +".mp3");
            }
            else 
            {
             new Player()
                .execute("http://www.qurandownloads.com/Audio/Yahya_Hawa/mp3/"+(position+1) +".mp3");
            }

Comment: thank you so much daniel, but i think it won't work with me because i have a media player that plays 114 Media file from url and the urls have numbers, so it depends on the position

check my code above

Comment: Where are the items on the list coming from? an ArrayList? a Cursor? Check my updated answer

Comment: thank you so much, im working on switch statement on adapter.getitem[position] and then i send int which is the position that i set depends on the adapter.getitem[position].